# IPC using posix unnamed semaphores

Tags: posix, ipc, semaphore

How to realize
producer/consmer problem in processes using anonymous posix semaphores?
(It means I need have 2 processes which print some text in turn, 2nd can be forked from 1st)

```
pthread_t pchild; 
int i = 0; 
pid_t pid; 

sem_init(&fst, 1, 1); 
sem_init(&scnd, 1, 0); 

if((pid = fork()) == 0){  

    while(i<10){ 
    sem_wait(&scnd); 
    printf("CHILD\n"); 
    sem_post(&fst); 
i++; 
} 
}else if(pid != -1){     

while(i<10){ 
        sem_wait(&fst); 
        printf("parent\n"); 
        sem_post(&scnd); 
        i++; 
        } 
}else{ printf("error - fork !!!\n");} 

sem_destroy(&fst); 
sem_destroy(&scnd);
```

this code prints just 
"parent" - 1 time,
but I found "Unnamed semaphores are either private, inherited through fork()" at the oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/sync-39/index.html
What's wrong?

---

my solution is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzgsyj9rq1ngv0s/ost_13p.c

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? It's not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: 2 process: 2nd is forked from 1st, both of them should print out something alternately. The task is make it using unnamed posix semaphores. As I understand that shared memory is a solution for this case, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the semaphores in shared memory (as by [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/shm_open.html)), and try again.

It's not enough to set the `pshared` argument in `sem_init`.  The memory referenced by the `sem_t *` argument must also be shared between processes.

Comment: >(as by shm_open)
I have to use unnamed semaphores

Comment: The *semaphores* will be unnamed.  If the shared memory must be unnamed, try MAP_ANONYMOUS/MAP_ANON or mapping `/dev/zero`.  If that doesn't work, `shm_open(O_EXCL)` on some mktemp-like names and then `shm_unlink()`.  Not perfect, but probably perfectly serviceable.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right(I read sem_open through lack of attantion)

Comment: well, my solution is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzgsyj9rq1ngv0s/ost_13p.c (maybe it will be useful for someone)